# Column width in multicol and using float environments

Tags: floats, margins, multicol

I'm trying to write my first report ever using LaTeX.
I want it to have two columns so I'm using the `multicol` package. The columns are too narrow though, I want it to be wide like, say, elsevier style articles.

Also is there really no way of inserting floats (figures, pgf graphics) into this two column setup? I need to show some images and make a graphic to show my experimental results.

Comment: Is using the [elsarticle](http://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) class an option for you?

Comment: @Santiago: floats work fine in a two-column layout. Perhaps as a separate question on that issue, with an example (we like to keep each question separate as otherwise it gets hard to follow what is going on).

Answer (score 4):

If you need an overall twocolumn layout, you could use the `twocolumn` option.

If you want to have a figure with a caption inside the `multicol` environment, you could use the [caption package](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/caption.html). The separation between the columns can be adjusted by the length `columnsep`. The width of the columns depends on the available text width, of course. See the following example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]

\bigskip
\rule{0.8\columnwidth}{1cm}
\captionof{figure}{A figure}\label{figure1}
\bigskip

\lipsum[3]
\end{multicols}
\chapter{Another chapter}
See figure~\ref{figure1}.
\begin{figure}%
\rule{0.8\columnwidth}{1cm}
\caption{Another figure}
\label{figure2}
\end{figure}
\chapter{A third chapter}
See figure~\ref{figure2}.
\end{document}
```

(The [`lipsum`package](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/lipsum.html) is only for producing the sample text, it is not part of the solution.)

Comment: @Santiago: The label works also with `\captionof`. I edited the example so that this can be seen.