# siunitx - Decimal points not present

Tags: tables, formatting, siunitx, multirow

Trying to use `siunitx` to make my columns look all nice and so such. However, The decimal points are absent...

Example:

[image: Example]

Code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,12pt]{article}

%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{science}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \onehalfspace
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    % \sisetup{group-digits=false,input-symbols={\%}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
    \bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}


%%% HEADERS & FOOTERS
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % This should be set AFTER setting up the page geometry
\pagestyle{fancy} % options: empty , plain , fancy
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % customise the layout...

\begin{document}
\begin{body}

\section*{Figures and Tables}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=2.142857142857143cm,y=2.142857142857143cm]
    \draw[-,color=black] (0,0) -- (3.5,0);
    \foreach \x in {,1,2,3}
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
    \draw[-,color=black] (0,0) -- (0,3.5);
    \foreach \y in {,1,2,3}
    \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
    \draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
    \clip(0,0) rectangle (3.5,3.5);
    \draw [shift={(0,0)}] plot[domain=-1.57:1.57,variable=\t]({1*3*cos(\t r)+0*3*sin(\t r)},{0*3*cos(\t r)+1*3*sin(\t r)});
    \draw [shift={(0,0)}] plot[domain=-1.57:1.57,variable=\t]({1*2*cos(\t r)+0*2*sin(\t r)},{0*2*cos(\t r)+1*2*sin(\t r)});
    \draw [shift={(0,0)}] plot[domain=-1.57:1.57,variable=\t]({1*1*cos(\t r)+0*1*sin(\t r)},{0*1*cos(\t r)+1*1*sin(\t r)});
    \draw [dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt] (0,2)-- (2.24,2);
    \draw [dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt] (0,1)-- (2.83,1);
    \begin{scriptsize}
    \draw[color=black] (3.11,1.25) node {Best Site};
    \draw[color=black] (1.26,0.64) node {Worst Site};
    \end{scriptsize}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A graph of an ideal free distribution}
    \end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\begin{tabular}{rSSSSS} \toprule
    Amount food in area A:              & {0\%} & {25\%} & {50\%} & {75\%} & {100\%} \\ \midrule
    \multirow{12}{*}{\parbox{7em}{\% Collembolans \\ in area A:}}    & 3.16 & 64.5 & 82.73 & 79 & 90.48 \\
                                        & 1.05 & 64.5 & 80.91 & 74 & 90.48 \\
                                        & 1.05 & 64.5 & 77.27 & 67 & 84.76 \\
                                        & 4 & 8 & 76.36 & 83 & 100 \\
                                        & 3.63 & 5.5 & 71 & 81 & 94 \\
                                        & 2 & 5 & 69 & 80 & 94 \\
                                        & 2 & 5 & 68 & 65 & 84.98 \\
                                        & 0.91 & 4.5 & 15 & 65 & 83.3 \\
                                        & 0 & 4.5    & 10 & 65 & 81.62 \\
                                        & 0 & ~ & 6 & ~ \\
                                        & 0 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
                                        & 0 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \midrule
            Average:                    & {89\%} & {73\%} & {56\%} & {25\%} & {1\%}

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{body}
\end{document}
```

Bonus points if you can tell me how to fix:

- Why when I put the above in a `\begin{table}` it disappears
- How I can split the multirow into 2 lines rather than stretching it out

Comment: The "disappearance" problem is caused by the `\body` environment, which is defined by the `science` package.  It uses `multicol` to set the body in two columns, and floats are disallowed in `multicols` environments. Unless you really need the `science` package for some specific requirement you probably shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want `S` columns. To load the package, use `\usepackage{siunitx}`, not the mix of lower and upper case you used. One way of splitting the multirow in 2 lines is to use a `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\begin{tabular}{rSSSSS} \toprule
    Amount food in area A:  & {0\%} & {25\%} & {50\%} & {75\%} & {100\%} \\ \midrule
    \multirow{12}{*}{\parbox{7em}{\% Collembolans \\ in area A:}}
             & 3.16 & 64.5 & 82.73 & 79 & 90.48 \\
             & 1.05 & 64.5 & 80.91 & 74 & 90.48 \\
             & 1.05 & 64.5 & 77.27 & 67 & 84.76 \\
             & 4 & 8 & 76.36 & 83 & 100 \\
             & 3.63 & 5.5 & 71 & 81 & 94 \\
             & 2 & 5 & 69 & 80 & 94 \\
             & 2 & 5 & 68 & 65 & 84.98 \\
             & 0.91 & 4.5 & 15 & 65 & 83.3 \\
             & 0 & 4.5    & 10 & 65 & 81.62 \\
             & 0 & ~ & 6 & ~ \\
             & 0 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\
             & 0 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \midrule
    Average: & {89\%} & {73\%} & {56\%} & {25\%} & {1\%}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The reason tables and figures disappear, is the `body` environment from the `science` package. This is defined as

```
\newenvironment{body}{\vspace{1pc}\begin{multicols}{2}}{\end{multicols}}
```

so it's basically a `multicols` environment with some space above it. Floats are not allowed in `multicols`. You could replace the `figure`/`table` environment with the `center` environment, load the `caption` package, and use `\captionof{figure}{A figure}` (replace `figure` with `table` for a table caption). However, your table is really too wide for a single column, so either use the `table*` environment which spans both columns, or make the table narrower, e.g. with Alan Munns suggestion.

Comment: Alternatively you could make the first column `>{\centering}p{1in}` and then use `{1in}` instead of `{*}` for the `\multirow` specification. This would make the first column narrower altogether.

Comment: You may want to add the command `\sisetup{group-digits=false,input-symbols={\%}}` in the preamble to avoid getting an unwanted separation between the numbers and the % sign in the header line and the final line.

Comment: @Mico Didn't notice that actually. However, your fix causes the zero in `0%` to disappear. Would one want the percent values to be aligned anyway? May be better to enclose all of them in braces instead.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Putting it in a \begin{table} still makes it disappear though. Any clue why?

Comment: @Zak No, I think you would have to make an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), as my example above works just fine.

Comment: Edited to add MWE. The only thing that shows up is the heading...

Comment: @Zak The problem is the `body` environment, which basically is a `multicols` environment with some space above it. Floats aren't allowed in `multicols`, hence it doesn't work, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11500/column-width-in-multicol-and-using-float-environments

Comment: @TorbjørnT. -- and I hadn't noticed the missing "0" in the first column if "input-symbols={\%}" is enabled! I like your workaround of encasing the entries in curly braces.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Is there a way for me to \end{body} and \begin something else? Is that kosher?

Comment: @Zak I'm not sure I understand. You want to `\begin{<something>} ... \end{body}`? Why? It won't work anyway.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. So that I'm not in the body environment and I can use floats?

Comment: @Zak As mentioned, the starred floating environments, `table*` and `figure*` work, though they span both columns. You can of course try and end the `body` environment, then add the figure, and start a new `body` after the figure, but I doubt that would work very well. I would suggest you ask a new question about this, unless you can find a solution by searching for older questions.